# Limit of $\sqrt{2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{\ldots}}}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I compute the limit of the sequence:
$$\sqrt{2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{\ldots}}}}$$
I tried:
$$x = \sqrt{2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{\ldots}}}}$$
$$x^2 = 2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{\ldots}}}$$
$$x^2 = 2^x$$
But this equation has more than one solution. How do I interpret this?

By trying, it seems that the sequence converges to 2.

---

The question arose by rewriting $2$
\begin{align*}
2 &=\sqrt{4}\\
2 &=\sqrt{2^\sqrt{4}}\\
2 &=\sqrt{2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{4}}}\\
  & \vdots\\
2 &= \sqrt{2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{2^\sqrt{\ldots}}}}
\end{align*}
But is this equal to the sequence in the beginning?

Comment: What is the first term in the series?

Comment: Technically, a "series" is a sum, so there is no "series" here. Essentially, such notation is not, technically, defined, but when we see such problems, we usually think of it as the limit of the sequence defined recursively $x_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2^{x_n}}$. Then you can prove that $x_n\leq 2$ and is increasing, so it must converge, and it thus has to converge to $2$.

Comment: I think I made a mistake... I think this is a Sequence and not a Series, right?

Comment: @Weker, yes, this is a sequence.  I updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Just a note $x$ can't be negative so you can remove one solution $x\approx -0.76$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing an expression with $\cdots$ in it doesn't *inherently* mean something. It's often a suggestive informal way to define the limit of a sequence, but if there's any confusion about what sequence it's the limit of, it just needs clarification.

In this case, you can define a sequence by the recurrence relation $$x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2^{x_n}}.$$ This doesn't uniquely specify the sequence, because we still need to add an initial condition $x_0$. I would say that the limit of any sequence you get by specifying a value of $x_0$ has some right to being referred to as $$\sqrt{2^{\sqrt{2^{\sqrt{2^{\dots}}}}}}.$$ (Because the starting value $x_0$ is "hidden inside the $\cdots$", we can't really say what it is from the expression, which is where the ambiguity comes from.)

If you set $x_0 = 2$, then we'll have $x_n = 2$ for all $n$, and the limit is (trivially) $2$. Also, if we set $x_0 = 4$, then we'll have $x_n = 4$ for all $n$, and the limit is (trivially) $4$.

More interesting is the fact that for any $x_0 \in (-\infty, 4)$, the limit will be $2$, and for any $x_0 \in (4,\infty)$, the limit is $\infty$ (that is, the sequence diverges). So $2$ is an attractor and $4$ is a repeller, and I think that if you had to give *some* single answer to what $$\sqrt{2^{\sqrt{2^{\sqrt{2^{\dots}}}}}}$$ is, it would be $2$.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$u_{n+1}^2=2^{u_n} $$
or
$$u_{n+1}=2^{\frac {u_n}{2}} $$

let $$f (x)=2^{\frac {x}{2} }$$
$f $ is increasing at $[0,+\infty) $.

$u_1=\sqrt {2}<u_2 \implies (u_n) $ increases.

by induction we prove that
$$\forall n\geq 1\;\, u_n<2$$

thus $(u_n) $ converges to the fixed point $x=2=f (2) $.

Answer (score 0):

If we define a sequence $x_n$ by the recurrence formula

$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2^{x_n}}$$

then the existence and value (if any) of the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ will depend on the choice of starting value $x_0$.  If we write $x_n=2(1+u_n)$, the recurrence becomes

$$u_{n+1}=2^{u_n}-1$$

The function $f(u)=2^u-1$ clearly satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.  It's easy to show that the iterates $f^{(n)}(u)=f(f^{(n-1)}(u))$ tend to $\infty$ if $u\gt1$ and $0$ if $u\lt1$.  All this corresponds to

$$x_n\to
\begin{cases}
\infty&\text{if }x_0\gt4\\
4&\text{if }x_0=4\\
2&\text{if }x_0\lt4\\
\end{cases}$$